# fstream::open() doesnt work - error reading characters from string

Tags: c++, file, visual-studio-2012, fstream

I am using vs2012 and need to take user input as file name to open the file.
(I use using namespace std; in the beginning of my programs so cout << basically means std::cout)

This code works for one of my projects but for others, the exact same code gives the error: 0xcccccccc "Error reading characters from string"

```
//this does not work
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


int main(){

    ifstream routesFile;
    string routesFileName;
        
    cout << "Please enter a filename for route database: ";
    cin >> routesFileName;

    routesFile.open(routesFileName.c_str()); 
    
    if (routesFile.fail())               
        cout << "Cannot open cannot open routes database file" << endl;
    
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

```
//this works
using namespace std;
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 
#include <sstream>
#include "strutils.h"


ifstream routesCheck(bool &exit)
{
    
    ifstream routesFile;
    string routesFileName;
    bool check = false;
    
    while(check == false)
    {
        
        cout << "Please enter a filename for route database: ";
        cin >> routesFileName;
        
        if(routesFileName == "EXIT")
        {exit = true; break;}

        routesFile.open(routesFileName.c_str()); 
    
        if (routesFile.fail())               
            cout << "Cannot open cannot open routes database file" << endl;
        
        else 
        {check = true; return routesFile;}

    }

}


ifstream timesCheck(bool &exit)
{
    
    ifstream timesFile;
    string timesFileName;
    bool check = false;
    
    while(check == false)
    {
        
        cout << "Please enter a filename for times database: ";
        cin >> timesFileName;

        if(timesFileName == "EXIT")
        {exit = true; break;}
    
        timesFile.open(timesFileName.c_str()); 
    
        if (timesFile.fail())               
            cout << "Cannot open cannot open times database file" << endl;
        
        else 
        {check = true; return timesFile;}

    }

}

double startTime(bool &exit)
{
    bool check = false;
    string startCheck = "", startCheckDummy="", foo=""; // foo is for converting char to string so that string to double converter can work
    double start = 0.0;

    while(check == false)
    {
        startCheck = ""; startCheckDummy=""; foo=""; start = 0.0;
        cout << "Please enter start time of arrival: ";
        cin >> startCheckDummy;

        if(startCheckDummy == "EXIT")
        {exit = true; break;}
        
        if(startCheckDummy.at(2) == ':' && startCheckDummy.at(0) >= 48 && startCheckDummy.at(0) <= 57 &&
           startCheckDummy.at(1) >= 48 && startCheckDummy.at(1) <= 57 && startCheckDummy.at(3) >= 48 && startCheckDummy.at(3) <= 57 && 
           startCheckDummy.at(4) >= 48 && startCheckDummy.at(4) <= 57)
        {
            startCheck += startCheckDummy.at(0);
            startCheck += startCheckDummy.at(1);
            startCheck += startCheckDummy.at(3);
            startCheck += startCheckDummy.at(4);

            foo = startCheck.at(0);
            start += atof(foo)*10;
            foo = startCheck.at(1);
            start += atof(foo);
            foo = startCheck.at(2);
            start += atof(foo)*0.1;
            foo = startCheck.at(3);
            start += atof(foo)*0.01;
            
            if(start >= 00.00 && start <= 23.59)
            {check = true; return start;}
            else
                cout << "Time is not in correct format" << endl;
        }
        else
            cout << "Time is not in correct format" << endl;
        
    }

    
}

void display(ifstream &routesFile, ifstream &timesFile, const double &routeStart, const string &depLoc) //delete const & if program doesnt work
{
    string r, t, depLocCheck, arrivalLoc, startCheckDummy, startCheck, foo;
    int routeID, timeID, startBabe = 0;
    double start = 0.0;
    cout << "The search results are: " << endl;
    
    while (getline(routesFile,r))
    {   
        istringstream routes(r);
         
        routes >> routeID >> depLocCheck >> arrivalLoc;
        
            if(depLocCheck == depLoc)
            {
                while (getline(timesFile,t))
                {
                    istringstream times(t);
                    times >> timeID >> startCheckDummy;
                    
                    startCheck = "";
                
                    startCheck += startCheckDummy.at(0);
                    startCheck += startCheckDummy.at(1);
                    startCheck += startCheckDummy.at(3);
                    startCheck += startCheckDummy.at(4);

                    start = atof(startCheck) / 100.0;
                    startBabe = atoi(startCheck) / 100;

                    if(timeID == routeID && start >= routeStart)
                    {
                        if(startBabe == start)
                        {
                            if(startBabe < 10)
                                {cout << depLoc << " " << arrivalLoc << " " << "0" << start << ".00" << endl;}
                            else
                                {cout << depLoc << " " << arrivalLoc << " " << start << ".00" << endl;}
                        }
                        else if(startBabe < 10)
                        {
                            cout << depLoc << " " << arrivalLoc << " " << "0" << start << endl;
                            if(startCheckDummy.at(4) == '0')
                                {cout << depLoc << " " << arrivalLoc << " " << start << "0" << endl;}
                        }
                        else if(startCheckDummy.at(4) == '0')
                            {cout << depLoc << " " << arrivalLoc << " " << start << "0" << endl;}
                        else
                            {cout << depLoc << " " << arrivalLoc << " " <<  start << endl;}
                    }
                    
                    start = 0.0;
                    
                    startBabe = 0;

                }
                timesFile.clear();
                timesFile.seekg(0);
            }

    }
    routesFile.clear();
    routesFile.seekg(0);
}


int main()
{
    bool exit = false;
    string depLoc;
    double start;
    ifstream routesFile, timesFile;
    
    routesFile = routesCheck(exit);

    timesFile = timesCheck(exit);

    cout << "Please enter departure location: ";
    cin >> depLoc;

    start = startTime(exit);

    while(!exit)
    {
        display(routesFile, timesFile, start, depLoc);
        cout << "Please enter departure location: ";
        cin >> depLoc;

        if(depLoc == "EXIT")
            exit = true;
        else
            start = startTime(exit);
    }

    cin.get();
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

I read that 0xccccccc error happens when theres a memory leak. I really cannot understand how it works for one of my projects but not for the others. I thought it had to do with where i put the input files but opening files using other methods work for other projects. So, i dont think it has to do with location. What might be the reason why it works for only one project? How do i fix it for other projects?

Comment: There's no reason that 'the exact same code' must work in one program simply because it works in another. The context is important. The code you have posted looks reasonable enough but it is incomplete, so the problem is somewhere in the code you haven't posted. In the context in other words. Please post minimal complete code that shows this problem, then the question can be answered.

Comment: PS your assumption about 0xCCCCCCCC meaning a memory leak is incorrect. On Windows it generally means that you are using uninitialised variables.

Comment: This is the whole code. Only difference in the program which this code block works is that the function return type is ifstream. I think there is something wrong outside my code.

Comment: There is no `main` function in the code you have posted, so it cannot be the whole code. Nor is there any reference parameter, function return etc. Please post a complete program. It is (frankly) very likely that the problem is in your code, but unless you share all of it, no-one is going to be able to tell you exactly what the error is,

Comment: This is quite a common situation we see here. You have some half formed theory of what might be wrong. You post only information that supports your idea, and are unwilling to post anything that might contradict it (like complete code). It's a form of confirmation bias. It's not a useful attitude to have if you want your problem solved. When you get more experienced you will realise that programming makes fools of us all, and that the blame for most bugs is ourselves.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I thought it would be unneccesary but now I added the whole code.

Comment: Could it be where the routes file is located in the project folder? And/or the way im adding the routes file to the project? I ve tried adding it to resource files and the routesfile is located where cpp files are, just like the project that works. I did not change any settings between projects.

Comment: I can see nothing wrong with your code. I tried running it and did not get the problem you see. (I'm not using the same compiler however). So I guess you are right, there is something wrong that is nothing to do with your code.

Comment: Is is the first program or the second program that has the problem? Because there are definitely problems with the second program (I only tested the first).

Comment: You should at least include <sstring> to try again. In a regular case, std::cin takes an instance of stringstream, not string, to accept inputs, because the internal buffer size in string could be implemented to any unspecific range and might fail if you pass chars long enough.

Comment: @john the second program works fine. What are the problems that you see? I didnt include other 3 functions which doesnt change any of these variables or use ifstream. Should i include them as well?

Comment: Yes you should include everything.

Comment: @DenizBatuStudent `ifstream routesCheck(bool &exit)` should not compile because `ifstream` lacks a copy constructor.

Comment: @Y.Z do you mean <sstream>?. Tried <sstream>, no change.

Comment: @john I do not yet know about copy constructors but the code compiles and works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the program compiles and runs just fine here.

Since I could not reproduce what you raise, I could only presume that you typed the string too long for it to hold. std::cin holds internal buffer of size x for user to input from standard device. String holds internal buffer of size y when an instance is created. x might not necessarily equal to or less than y. Therefore, program may fault in case that user passes long text that the length of which surpassed the capacity of string.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is solved. I have updated vs2012 and added strutils.h to the new project. I still get the same error message but somehow the file opens without an issue. Still have no clue why.

Comment: The reason is a common one, there is bug somewhere in your code. Bugs often cause programs to behave 'randomly' so changes which seem irrelevant can make a big difference. Sometimes bugged programs even work completely correctly. Anything is possible when you have bugs.

Comment: Incidentally it is not solved if you are still getting the error message. Your program will continue to behave strangely as long as the bug is not fixed. It's not a good situation to be in as it will make future development difficult if small changes to your code make unpredicatable changes to how your program behaves. You should stop future development until you have genuinely found out what the problem really is.